# Lumen api include html error in every response

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I have a lumen app (version 5.7.8) that when i call some route locally it returns the correct response but after that it includes the html error in the response text.

For example, i have this controller with a simple test method which return just a string:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Testing;

class PabloController{
    public function test(){
        return 'something';
    }
}
```

This is the route in web.php:

```
<?php
$router->post('/test', 'Testing\PabloController@test');
```

And there you can see the response in postman which include the string response and the html from the error template (/resources/views/Errors/general.blade.php):

[image]

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try return it as:

```
        return response([
              'success' => true,
              'data' => 'something'
            ], 200);
```

Comment: Not change, it includes the html code at the end

Comment: Have you set a custom error exception recently in your lumen app?

Comment: If it answer your question, please accept it as an an answer :)